# Hamcrest CombinableMatcher - Generic Method won't compile

Tags: java, generics

I've just been looking at the 'both' and 'and' methods on the org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher in hamcrest 1.2

For some reason, I can't get the following to compile

```
@Test
public void testBoth() {
    String HELLO = "hello";
    String THERE = "there";
    assertThat("hello there", both(containsString(HELLO)).and(containsString(THERE)));
}
```

The compilation message I get is

```
and(org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.lang.Object>) in org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher<java.lang.Object> cannot be applied to (org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.String>)
```

If i specify the type parameter explicity for the method, it works

```
@Test
public void testBoth() {
    String HELLO = "hello";
    String THERE = "there";
    Assert.assertThat("hello there", CombinableMatcher.<String>
        both(containsString(HELLO)).and(containsString(THERE)));
}
```

Although this is not nearly as nice.

Can anyone tell me why the compiler can't figure out the types here? I can't believe this is the expected behaviour in this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The compiler should infer `LHS <: String` (§15.12.2.7 [(A)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#340410) then [(B)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#340432)) from which of course it can trivially deduce `LHS = String`. JDK 7 honors the spec (and you can specify the source and target as 5 as in `javac -source 5 -target`).

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar compile error (while using java 1.8 and hamcrest 1.3) because my first matcher was `nullValue()` which returns type `Object`.

```
assertThat(BigDecimal.ONE, 
    is(both(not(nullValue()))
        .and(not(comparesEqualTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)))));
         ^---The method and(Matcher<? super Object>) in the type 
             CombinableMatcher.CombinableBothMatcher<Object> is not
             applicable for the arguments (Matcher<BigDecimal>)
```

If you use `nullValue(BigDecimal.class)`, it will compile.

```
assertThat(BigDecimal.ONE, 
    is(both(not(nullValue(BigDecimal.class)))
        .and(not(comparesEqualTo(BigDecimal.ZERO)))));
```